# Select only newest Entries of DB

Tags: mysql

I've got a database which has the table updates which contains: product_name, environment, version, date, task.

I need to select only the newest of all and all at one date in time.

Comment: show us your db, and queries you have tried

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is a fine website to learn SQL with realtime examples!

Comment: something like `select * from table order by date desc limit 1;`

Comment: @Anil There are multiple products in the table, I need to get all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something following will give you all records from max date of each product

`select * from table allDates JOIN
 ( select max(date) maxdate, product from table group by product) maxDates
allDates.Date= maxDates.maxdate and allDates.product= maxDates.product`

for all products of latest date

`select * from table where date =
 ( select max(date) maxdate from table)`

Answer (score 0):

> the newest of all

Anil had a good idea with

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

> all at one date in time

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date) = '2017-11-06'
```

or if your date contains more than just year, month and day

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date LIKE '2017-11-06%'
```